# Init char array sensibly in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have a class respectively a struct with a member variable of type `std::array<char, 100>` called charArray. I want to initialize this array sensibly. Which values are sensible to init the array with and what is the best way to do this?

I think I could use `std::fill()` in constructor but is this the way I should  really do it? I mean because of initialization vs. assignment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to value initialize the array to the type's default value.  Take for example

```
struct Foo
{
    std::array<int, 10> bar;
    Foo() : bar({}) {}
};
```

Here `bar` is would be initialized to all 0's.  You can compare that with

```
struct Bar
{
    std::array<int, 10> baz;
};
```

Which would default initialize `baz` and its elements would have an indeterminate value.  You can see all of this working with

```
struct Foo
{
    std::array<int, 10> bar;
    Foo() : bar({}) {}
};

struct Bar
{
    std::array<int, 10> baz;
};


int main(){
    Foo foo;
    for (auto e : foo.bar)
        std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    Bar bar;
    for (auto e : bar.baz)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Possible output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-917263728 4197632 4197632 4197632 4197632 4197632 6295552 0 4197581 0
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bc1cfae73241d28)</kbd>

Comment: Did you mean "baz' elements would have an *in*determinant value"?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Typo Fixed.  Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I am not sure if reading them is UB or not.

Comment: It's a bit hidden, but 4.1 in the 2011 standard makes any "lvalue-to-rvalue" conversion (which must happen somewhere to the elements of `bar.baz` behind the screen of iterators and operator calls)  undefined behavior "if the object is uninitialized". [DR 616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3714.html) will not change that for automatic variables. The reason must be architectures with "uninitialized" flags or outright trap representations in registers.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider But since the array values get *default initialized* does that still count?

Comment: 8.5/6: To default-initialize an object of type T means:
— if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type [...]
— if T is an array type [...]
— otherwise, **no initialization is performed.**